# MongoDB vs Mysql Storage space compare

Tags: mysql, mongodb, storage

I am building a data ware house that is the range of 15+ TBs. While storage is cheap, but due to limited budget we have to squeeze as much data as possible in to that space while maintaining performance and flexibility since the data format changes quiet frequently.

I tried Infobright(community edition) as a SQL solution and it works wonderful in term of storage and performance, but the limitation on data/table alteration is making it almost a no go. and infobright's pricing on enterprise version is quiet steep.

After checking out MongoDB, it seems promising except one thing. I was in a chat with a 10gen guy, and he stated that they don't really give much of a thought in term of storage space since they flatten out the data to achieve the performance and flexibility, and in their opinion storage is too cheap nowadays to be bother with.

So any experienced mongo user out there can comment on its storage space vs mysql (as it is the standard for what we comparing against to right now). if it's larger or smaller, can you give rough ratio? I know it's very situation dependent on what sort of data you put in SQL and how you define the fields, indexing and such... but I am just trying to get a general idea.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You might want to investigate PostgreSQL too.

Comment: If I can find some time to set up another demo DB I would check into Postgre... the main debate right now is more on NoSQL vs SQL in the company :(

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB is not optimized for small disk space - as you've said, "disk is cheap".

From what I've seen and read, it's pretty difficult to estimate the required disk space due to:

- Padding of documents to allow in-place updates
- Attribute names are stored in each collection, so you might save quite a bit by using abbreviations
- No built in compression (at the moment)
- ...

IMHO the general approach is to build a prototype, insert data and see how much disk space your specific use case requires. The more realistic you can model your queries (inserts and updates) the better your result will be.

For more details see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will start dumping in some data and see if I can see a obvious difference.

Answer (score 3):

**Pros and Cons of MongoDB**

For the most part, users seem to like MongoDB. Reviews on TrustRadius give the document-oriented database 8.3 out of 10 stars.

Some of the things that authenticated MongoDB users say they like about the database include its:

- Scalability.
- Readable queries.
- NoSQL.
- Change streams and graph queries.
- A flexible schema for altering data elements.
- Quick query times.
- Schema-less data models.
- Easy installation.

Users also have negative things to say about MongoDB. Some cons reported by authenticated users include:

- User interface, which has a fairly steep learning curve.
- Lack of joins, which can make some data retrieval projects difficult.
- Occasional slowness in the cloud environment.
- High memory consumption
- Poorly structured documentation.
- Lack of built-in analytics.

**Pros and Cons of MySQL**

MySQL gets a slightly higher rating (8.6 out of 10 stars) on TrustRadius than MongoDB. Despite the higher rating, authenticated users still mention plenty of pros and cons of choosing MySQL.

Some of the positive features that users mention frequently include MySQL’s:

- Portability that lets it connect to secondary databases easily.
- Ability to store relational data.
- Fast speed.
- Excellent reliability.
- Exceptional data security standards.
- User-friendly interface that helps beginners complete projects.
- Easy configuration and management.
- Quick processing.

Of course, even people who enjoy using MySQL find features that they don’t like. Some of their complaints include:

- Reliance on SQL, which creates a steeper learning curve for users who
  do not know the language.
- Lack of support for full-text searches in InnoDB tables.
- Occasional stability issues.
- Dependence on add-on features.
- Limitations on fine-tuning and common table expressions.
- Difficulties with some complex data types.

**MongoDB vs MySQL Performance**

When comparing the performance of MongoDB and MySQL, you must consider how each database will affect your projects on a case-by-case basis. While some performance features may appear to be objectively promising, your team members may never use the features that drew you to a database in the first place.

**MongoDB Performance**

Many people claim that MongoDB outperforms MySQL because it allows them to create queries in multiple ways. To put it another way, MongoDB can be used without knowing SQL. While the flexibility improves MongoDB's performance for some organizations, SQL queries will suffice for others.

MongoDB is also praised for its ability to handle large amounts of unstructured data. Depending on the types of data you collect, this feature could be extremely useful.

MongoDB does not bind you to a single vendor, giving you the freedom to improve its performance. If a vendor fails to provide you with excellent customer service, look for another vendor.

**MySQL Performance**

MySQL performs extremely well for teams that want an open-source relational database that can store information in multiple tables. The performance that you get, however, depends on how well you configure the MySQL database. Configurations should differ depending on the intended use. An e-commerce site, for example, might need a different MySQL configuration than a team of research scientists.

No matter how you plan to use MySQL, the database’s performance gets a boost from full-text indexes, a high-speed transactional system, and memory caches that prevent you from losing crucial information or work.

If you don’t get the performance that you expect from MySQL data warehouses and databases, you can improve performance by integrating them with an excellent ETL tool that makes data storage and manipulation easier than ever.

**MySQL vs MongoDB Speed**

In most speed comparisons between MySQL and MongoDB, MongoDB is the clear winner. MongoDB is much faster than MySQL at accepting large amounts of unstructured data. When dealing with large projects, it's difficult to say how much faster MongoDB is than MySQL. The speed you get depends on a number of factors, including the bandwidth of your internet connection, the distance between your location and the database server, and how well you organise your data.

If all else is equal, MongoDB should be able to handle large data projects much faster than MySQL.

**Choosing Between MySQL and MongoDB**

Whether you choose MySQL or MongoDB probably depends on how you plan to use your database.

**Choosing MySQL**

For projects that require a strong relational database management system, such as storing data in a table format, MySQL is likely to be the better choice. MySQL is also a great choice for cases requiring data security and fault tolerance. MySQL is a good choice if you have high-quality data that you've been collecting for a long time.

Keep in mind that to use MySQL, your team members will need to know SQL. You'll need to provide training to get them up to speed if they don't already know the language.

**Choosing MongoDB**

When you want to use data clusters and search languages other than SQL, MongoDB may be a better option. Anyone who knows how to code in a modern language will be able to get started with MongoDB. MongoDB is also good at scaling quickly, allowing multiple teams to collaborate, and storing data in a variety of formats.

Because MongoDB does not use data tables to make browsing easy, some people may struggle to understand the information stored there. Users can grow accustomed to MongoDB's document-oriented storage system over time.